# In place TFS 2012 to TFS 2013 upgrade?

Tags: tfs

We have created a VM clone of our TFS server (but haven't turned on networking yet for the clone).
We have created a test SQL server that we plan on using for the test upgrade.

I'm not sure what we should do first (after populating the tfs databases on the test SQL server).
Since our test TFS server is a VM clone, TFS is installed and configured already. The Cloned TFS server is pointing to our production SQL server. Are the following steps correct:

1. Turn on networking for the Cloned TFS server
2. Remote into the Cloned TFS server
3. Run command TFSServiceControl quiesce
4. Run the command TFSConfig PrepareClone
5. Run the command TFSConfig ChangeServer ID
6. Run the command TFSConfig RemapDBS
7. Update the TFS URLS in the admin console
8. Edit Reporting to point to the new test Reporting instance
9. Update all service accounts

Are the steps correct? I am not sure which order to carry out the steps out after the TFS databases have been put on the test SQL server. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing the following:

- Unconfigure your test server. I assume you don't want to upgrade your production server yet, you just want to test the upgrade, correct? If that's the case run 'TfsConfig.exe setup /Uninstall:All' to unconfigure the new server.
- (if you haven't done it already) Backup all TFS databases from production server. You'll need all DBs with the names starting with 'Tfs_' including Tfs_Configuration, Tfs_Warehouse and all collection databases.
- Restore TFS backups from production on VM or some other test SQL server (using SQL server management studio)
- Run tfsconfig changeserverid command (on the new server) to change the TFS server id. It's required because you want to have both TFS instances live for some time. If you don't do it, VS clients will think that it's the same server (even though the name is different) and this can cause some issues.
- Run tfsconfig remapdbs command (on the new server) which will fix the old Tfs_Configuration database. This is only required because you are moving TFS to a different machine (with a different name)
- Now you can start TFS management console and perform the actual upgrade which is pretty straightforward. Upgrade wizard will ask you for the new service account names and new test reporting instance location.

Comment: I appreciate the information but wanted to ask something else.

Comment: We are planning on blocking traffic on the test TFS server to all production servers. That way we can turn on networking and remote into the test TFS server. Will running the Unconfigure command impact the production servers at all? Should we run the PrepareClone command before doing the uncofigure command? It looks like the PrepareClone command removes backup schedule info, sharepoint, and reporting resources.

Comment: Answering your questions: no, unconfigure command won't affect production and yes, you should run PrepareClone command before running the upgrade.
I'm not sure I understand why do you need to block traffic on the test server. Test server should be using it's own copy of the production databases, that's the key point. You cannot just upgrade the binaries, 2013 binaries won't work with 2012 database, you need to upgrade TFS database to 2013 version as well. That's why in the approach I suggest it doesn't matter if you block traffic or not, test server won't depend on the production environment.

Comment: Dont want to unconfig everything on Cloned TFS Server. I only want to point the cloned TFS server to test sql server that have been populated with data from TFS. The reason we want to block traffic from the cloned TFS and the production environment is because that cloned TFS server is currently pointing at our production sql server. We have networking turned off right now on the cloned tfs. We need to turn on networking so we can access the cloned tfs server. If we turn it on,it will still be pointing to production sql. We want to block traffic,turn it on, then point to test sql server?

Comment: How are you planning to point cloned server to test sql server? Changing the URLs won't change the database connection string which means that cloned server will still point to the production DB and there's no way to change it without unconfiguring TFS first.

Comment: Was planning to do: 1) Prepare Clone 2) Changeserverid 3) remap dbs 4) change urls 5) update service accounts 6) reconfigure build server. Shouldn't the remap dbs point TFS to its new test dbs?